# JScrollPane nullifies the width attribute of my JList cells

Tags: java, swing

I have a **JFrame** which consists only of a **JList**, the **JList** has its own cell renderer, in the cell renderer a **JTextPane** is returned with a custom size. The custom size has the result that the lines of this text panes are wrapped.

```
textPane.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Now I want to make this JList scrollable, so I wrap it into a JScrollPane component, this however, nullifies the width constraints I have defined in the cell renderer. What would be the best way to enforce the width constraint in the JScrollPane?

```
setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

DefaultListModel<Status> listModel = new DefaultListModel<Status>();
JList<Status> list = new JList<>(listModel);
list.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
list.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
list.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
// wrap the list with a JScrollPane
add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: setSize doesn't make sense (and doesn't have any effect): sizing and locating of components is the _exclusive_ job of the LayoutManager. Instead, let your rendering component return a reasonable preferredSize (which determines the list's pref)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render operation of `Cell` is done by `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI` class, and it will paint whole case, no matter what size you set for cell renderer. You can dig into the source code of `BasicListUI` class to understand how it works.

I guess you just to make sure the content of the cell can be all displayed. In this case, you can add a horizontal scroll bar for the list. To do this, get a preferred width for the list.

Like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);

    JList list = new JList(new Object[]{ "11", "22" })
    {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return new Dimension(1000, 800);
        }
    };
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I set the preferredSize of the JList to the same width as I set the width of the cell I return with my ListCellRenderer and  it did all I wanted. Why do you overwrite the getter method for this?

Comment: setPreperredSize() not always working, it depends on whether component remember the size or not. overwrite getPreferredSize() will  ensure the size is passed in.